# Flutter widgets are not getting laid out correctly

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The `ListView` widget which is getting generated as part of the `CourseStream` Stream Builder isn't getting laid out correctly, as shown in the picture below. I don't see any errors within the `Debug Console`.

[image: There is an unusual space between the Courses row and the Categories row]

Below is the code for the `CourseStream` which contains the `ListView`.

```
final coursesCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('courses').limit(10).where('courseLive', isEqualTo: true);

class CourseStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: coursesCollection.snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: kBrandColor),
            );
          }
        }

        final courseListStream = snapshot.data!.docs.map((course) {
          return CourseData.fromDocument(course);
        }).toList();

        List<BadgedCourseCard> courseCards = [];

        for (var course in courseListStream) {
          final courseDocID = course.courseDocID;
          final courseID = course.courseID;
          final courseTitle = course.courseTitle;
          final courseDescription = course.courseDescription;
          final courseSubTitle = course.courseSubTitle;
          final courseBadge = course.courseBadge;
          final courseLevel = course.courseLevel;
          final coursePaid = course.coursePaid;
          final courseImage = course.courseImage;
          final courseBgColor = hexToColor(course.courseBackgroundColor.toString());
          final courseBgColor1 = hexToColor(course.courseBgColor1.toString());
          final courseBgColor2 = hexToColor(course.courseBgColor2.toString());
          final courseFgColor = hexToColor(course.courseFgColor.toString());
          final courseDeliveryFormat = course.courseDeliveryFormat;
          final courseLive = course.courseLive;

          final badgedCourseCard = BadgedCourseCard(
            courseTitle: courseTitle.toString(),
            courseTitleTextColor: courseFgColor,
            cardBackgroundColor: courseBgColor,
            courseImage: courseImage.toString(),
            courseCardTapped: () => print("Course Card Tapped"),
            courseBookmarkTapped: () => print("Course Bookmark Tapped"),
          );

        return ListView(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: courseCards,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the code where the `ListView` is getting consumed.

```
class AppHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppHomeState createState() => _AppHomeState();
}

class _AppHomeState extends State<AppHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        leading: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.5.w),
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(ScaledAnimationPageRoute(AppDrawer())),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.sort,
              color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
              size: 6.5.w,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 2.5.w),
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: null,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                size: 6.5.w,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.w),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CardHeader(
              leadingText: "Courses",
              trailingText: "View All",
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 1.h),
            Expanded(child: CourseStream()),
            SizedBox(height: 2.h),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not sure from where exactly the space is getting added below the `Courses` row. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try adding this inside the ListView? `padding: EdgeInsets.zero`

Comment: No, I haven't tried it. Do you mean to say adding padding to the `ListView` widget?

Comment: I just tried adding `padding: EdgeInsets.zero` to the `ListView` but still have the same issue. Thanks for your help @kmtz

Comment: Try adding both `padding: EdgeInsets.zero` and `shrinkWrap:true` and see if this will help.

Comment: another solution might be to wrap `ListView` inside `MediaQuery.removePadding(removeBottom: true, child: ListView()`

Comment: Actually I see something now, you wrapped `Courses` inside `Expanded` and that is the reason why it takes more space. Try using `Flexible` instead.

Comment: Tried everything you suggested @kmtz, but still, it's the same. Not sure what exactly is causing this issue. Feel like banging my head on the wall. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but did you actually hot reloaded the app? Sometimes it needs that in order to apply changes. I had similar problem as you and I have solved it with one of those things that I wrote. I was feeling the same, so no worries you will find a solution eventually.

Comment: And try to remove `Expanded` completely. Just call `CourseStream()`

Comment: Sorry for spamming but add to the `Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children:[...])` and see if this will help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234815/discussion-between-xpetta-and-kmtz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the chat, this may be a solution for it.
Remove `Expanded` from `Column()` and wrap `ListView` with `SizedBox` so that you can limit height.

```
return SizedBox(
       height: 20.5.h,
       child: ListView(
         physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
         scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
         children: courseCards,
      ),
);
```